# csvsimple struggles with loading UTF-8 characters

Tags: unicode, csvsimple

I am trying to get `csvsimple` to load a table column and display its contents in an enumerated list. I got to a point where it works for ASCII characters and even some letters with diacritics, but it breaks down in a very strange way when characters from other scripts (including even the International Phonetic Alphabet) are included. This is unexpected, as I'm using XeLaTeX and haven't yet experienced such behavior in it.

This is my `example.csv`:

```
Column
abcd
a ą b c ć
1234
что
はなす
μέγα
Færøerne 
中国
ɨnyuɬumʼu
```

And my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\csvloop{
    file = {example.csv},
    head to column names,
    command = \Column,
    before line = \item,
    filter not strcmp = {\Column}{},
    before reading = {\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]},
    after reading = {\end{enumerate}}
}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get in the pdf:

[image: csvsimple mishandling UTF-8 characters]

I wasn't able to find out why this behavior would occur. The code doesn't just ignore all these characters, after all `filter not strcmp = {\Column}{}` would eliminate empty rows. There's also something funny going on with the invisible text, I get `Færøern` when I highlight `8. 9.` and copy-paste it.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `csvsimple`: you have not chosen an appropriate font setup to display all of those characters

Comment: don't ignore all the missing character warnings.